# add Add to Cart button on an HTML page for nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

I am setting up an nopcommerce site for a customer. This client only has 2 products for now. The client wants to have a Calculator page which will allow the user to plug in a few values for a specific product and the page will inform the user, how much quantity of that product they should purchase.

I am thinking of building this calculator page as a simple HTML page. The client wants to place an Add To Cart button next to the calculated quantity. This way, the user can easily add the product to cart after calculating the correct quantity. How should I go about implementing this in nopCommerce. Basically, how do I place an Add To Cart button on this custom page?

New to nopcommerce, any guidance is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a button to any place on the site, if you know some product properties, like Id and 'DisableBuyButton'. You can look how it's done in the Views\Shared\_ProductBox.cshtml (ver 3.40).

It should look like this:

```
//prepare "Add to cart" AJAX link
string addtocartlink = "";
var shoppingCartTypeId = (int)ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart;
var quantity = 1;

addtocartlink = Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart-Catalog", new { productId = Model.Id, shoppingCartTypeId = shoppingCartTypeId, quantity = quantity, });


@if (!Model.ProductPrice.DisableBuyButton)
{
    <input type="button" value="@T("ShoppingCart.AddToCart")" class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button" onclick="AjaxCart.addproducttocart_catalog('@addtocartlink    ');return false;" />
}
```

for reference check on _AddToCart.cshtml view file